# Facebook Registration Widget optional fields?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, registration

I'm implementing the Facebook registration widget into our web app, and we've got a couple of demographics questions we are asking on login.  Now, these fields are supposed to be optional, but the widget is requiring them to be answered before the user can register.  Is there any way to declare them as optional?  I've tried searching and haven't really found anything that answers my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no - they aren't, despite Facebook's documentation to the contrary.